# Get type handle for generic class parameter

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have the following class:

```
namespace MyClassLibrary
{
   public class CalculatorGeneric<T>  where T : IMyInterface
   {

      public int Value1 { get; set; }
      public int Value2 { get; set; }
      public CalculatorGeneric()
      {
         Value1 = 100;
         Value2 = 200;
      }

      public int Add(int val1, int val2)
      {
         Value1 = val1; Value2 = val2;
         return val1 + Value2;
      }

      public int Multiply(int val1, int val2)
      {

         Value1 = val1; Value2 = val2;

         return Value1 * Value2;
      }

   }
}
```

Somewhere else in my code, I prejit all methods in my solution with the following method:

```
  public static void PreJitAllMethods(Type type)
  {
     // get the type of all the methods within this instance
     var methods = type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly |
                                 BindingFlags.NonPublic |
                                 BindingFlags.Public |
                                 BindingFlags.Instance |
                                 BindingFlags.Static);
     if (type.IsGenericType)
     {
       // return;
     }

     // Jit all methods
     foreach (var method in methods)
     {
        // jitting of the method happends here.
        try
        {
           if (type.IsGenericType)
              RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod(method.MethodHandle, new[] { typeof(object).TypeHandle });
           else
              RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod(method.MethodHandle);
        }
        catch  (Exception ex)
        {

        }
     }
  }
```

Without the `where T : IMyInterface I` can just pass the parameter `new[] { typeof(object).TypeHandle }` But my problem is, I also need to call the method RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod for class methods where the generic parameter contains for example `where T: IMyInterface`. How can I do this?

Comment: Use [`.GetGenericParameterConstraints`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getgenericparameterconstraints?view=netframework-4.8)? Also, are you sure that this is a good thing to be doing? Would it not be better to use ngen or such?

Comment: or .NET Core 3 includes AOT JIT features which would do all of this at build time, IIRC

Comment: I have tried the GetGenericParameterConstrains, but it returns this: type.GetGenericTypeDefinition().TypeHandle
{System.RuntimeTypeHandle}
    Value: 0x015352c4
    m_type: {Name = "CalculatorGeneric`1" FullName = "MyClassLibrary.CalculatorGeneric`1"} I can't use ngen as our project has to run in the azure cloud. I also can't use .NET Core, as it would mean we will have to refactor a lot of assemblies...